# How to exclude root directories when you zip the folder in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, zip

i am trying to zip a folder , which is located 4 levels beneath the root folder,
i am able to zip the folder, but it contains the root folders as well.

```
     using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
           {

     zip.AddSelectedFiles("*",filepath,string.empty,false);
     zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
            }
```

My need is to zip only that perticular file not the entire folder structure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this example:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    // files in the filesystem like MyDocuments\ProjectX\File1.txt, will be
    // stored in the zip archive as backup\File1.txt
    zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "backup");

    // files in the filesystem like MyMusic\Santana\OyeComoVa.mp3, will be
    // stored in the zip archive as tunes\Santana\OyeComoVa.mp3
    zip.AddDirectory("MyMusic", "tunes");

    // The Readme.txt file in the filesystem will be stored in the zip
    // archive as documents\Readme.txt
    zip.AddDirectory("Readme.txt", "documents");

    zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
    zip.Save(ZipFileToCreate);
}
```

Reference: http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html